Update a SharePoint list item based on another item in the same list
I'm attempting to update a SharePoint list item based on another item's value in the same list. The column I'm testing is called "EOP Response Documentation", which is multiline text. If this item is not empty then I need the list item "EOP Document Status" to change it's value to "Draft in Review". Otherwise it should remain at the default value of "Not Started". The flow I'm working on looks like this. This item is a dropdown choice, single select only, "Not started", "Draft in Review", and "Completed".
Here's a link to the Microsoft site that has screen shots of what I've attempted to do far. Link
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

"EOP Response Documentation" - is this a "plain text" column or "rich text" column?

Plain text at the moment.

I did figure out how to make the flow work based on a condition step. Unfortunately, I've now created two other issues.

I do have have 2 things to work out.
First, when I changed this flow from a manually triggered flow to "When an item is created or modified", it will run as an infinite loop. I don't know what to do to keep this from happening.
Second, I had already built an automated email that triggers when the status is changed to "Draft in Review". In both the manual and when "When an item is created or modified" flow are ran, a new email is sent for every row that has "draft in Review". Again, I don't know what to do to keep this from happening.
